# JavaScript move an image with arrow keys

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-animate, key, move

I've seen lots of people ask similar questions here, but none of them seem to work for me. I have an img, with the id 'character'. I want it to move left on left click and right on right click. This is the code I have:

```
var bound = window.innerWidth;
function left(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.left.match(/^([0-9]+)/);
    var current = RegExp.$1; 
    if(current <=bound){
        document.getElementById(id).style.left = current - 0 + 'px';
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById(id).style.left = current - 5 + 'px';
    }
}

function right(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.left.match(/^([0-9]+)/);
    var current = RegExp.$1;
    if(current >= (bound - 5){
        document.getElementById(id).style.left = current + 0 + 'px';
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById(id).style.left = current + 1 + 'px';
    }
}

document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;       
function KeyCheck() {

    var KeyID = event.keyCode;
    switch(KeyID)
    {
    case 39:
    right('character');
    break;
     case 37:
    left('character');
    break;
    }
}
```

I don't know if I should fix this code, or if there is something simpler. If you have a simpler way of doing this, please let me know.

Comment: What is the error you have?

Comment: It works fine going left, but when it goes right, it jumps like 30 px, then like 100px, so on, farther and farther each time.

Comment: Your steps are different in the left and right function. use one variable to avoid that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use jQuery?

```
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
  var max = $('body').width();
  var min = 0;
  var move_amt = 10;
  var position = $("#my_image").offset();
  if(e.which == 37) { // left
    var new_left = ((position.left-move_amt < min) ? min : position.left-move_amt);
    $("#my_image").offset({ left: new_left})
  }
  else if(e.which == 39) { // right
    var new_left = ((position.left+move_amt > max) ? max : position.left+move_amt);
    $("#my_image").offset({ left: new_left})
  }
});
```

Here is a [demo of it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/nhYN3/3/)

Comment: Thanks. I completely forgot about that.

Comment: I didn't implement the bounds checking, let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: That would be awesome, if you don't mind. I think I'm calling the size of the window incorrectly. I tried making an if statement, where, basically, if the value of #img.style.left was less than the width of the entire window, then it wouldn't animate, but that didn't work. Or, if you know a better way, that's good too.

Comment: I added bounds checking to the example and the demo. Right now I have it limiting the right bounds based on `body`. You could change that to any container you need.

Comment: When I do that, it works, but it can only move in "chunks". How can I make it move if the key is being held down, instead of being pressed once?

Comment: The problem is that the `animate` function takes some time to move the image. If you hold down the key, this function gets called so fast that the animation never has time to complete before calling it again with the same values. I've updated to directly set the `left` position without using any animation to allow holding down the button

Answer (score 0):

Your steps are different in the left and right function. use one variable to avoid that. Example

```
 var step = 5;
function left(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.left.match(/^([0-9]+)/);
    var current = RegExp.$1; 
    if(current <=bound){
        document.getElementById(id).style.left = current - 0 + 'px';
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById(id).style.left = current - step + 'px';
    }
}

function right(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.left.match(/^([0-9]+)/);
    var current = RegExp.$1;
    if(current >= (bound - 5){
        document.getElementById(id).style.left = current + 0 + 'px';
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById(id).style.left = current + step + 'px';
    }
}
```