# Html: How to dynamically move a Image using the arrow keys?

Tags: html, css, image, dynamic, position

I am trying to make an image move on my command (the arrow keys), using CSS.

I thought about this:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<script>
    function a() {
    // k is a global variable but i dont know how to declare it
        document.getElementById("img1").style.top = k + "px";
        k++;
        // and also i dont know how to trigger the function using the arrow keys
    }
</script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <img id="img1" src="IMAGES/logo.jpg" height="100" width="100"
           style="position:absolute; left:100px; top:100px; z-index:1" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use onkeypress event using JavaScript to capture the keypress events of your keyboard.

for eg:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="myFunction()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nhYN3/36/

```
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
  var max = $('body').width();
  var min = 0;
  var move_amt = 10;
  var position = $("#my_image").offset();
  if(e.which == 37) { // left
    var new_left = ((position.left-move_amt < min) ? min : position.left-move_amt);
    $("#my_image").offset({ left: new_left})
  }
  else if(e.which == 39) { // right
    var new_left = ((position.left+move_amt > max) ? max : position.left+move_amt);
    $("#my_image").offset({ left: new_left})
  }
});
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15915630/1837329)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript only (without jQuery), it would look like this:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", moveImage, false);

var img = document.getElementById('img1');
//The amount of pixels to move the image by with each keypress.
var moveJump = 10;

function moveImage(e) {
    var kc = e.keyCode;
    //Gets the current "top" value minus the "px" as an int.
    var top = parseInt(img.style.top.substr(0, img.style.top.length - 2));
    //Gets the current "left" value minus the "px" as an int.
    var left = parseInt(img.style.left.substr(0, img.style.left.length - 2));

    switch (kc) {
        case 37:
            //Pressed left.
            img.style.left = (left - moveJump) + 'px';
            break;
        case 38:
            //Pressed up.
            img.style.top = (top - moveJump) + 'px';
            break;
        case 39:
            //Pressed right.
            img.style.left = (left + moveJump) + 'px';
            break;
        case 40:
            //Pressed down.
            img.style.top = (top + moveJump) + 'px';
            break;
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/auwchLdn/2/